# Cannot detect the USB keyboard during Windows XP installation

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, installation, keyboard

My friend has an old computer which needs to reinstall Windows. So I format the machine and try to install a brand new copy of Windows XP.

The process was all fine, until a message pops out, something like "The USB driver may not be suitable to your device, do you want to continue?" Either I answer Yes or No, the keyboard is not answering anymore, but the machine is still working as I saw that the background is still moving.

The installation process sucks at this point. I have tried to do it all over again (for 4 times LOL), but it still cannot work.

I have change the BIOS settings as well, to enabled the "USB Legacy Support".

Does anyone know the reason? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: that's a toughie, is there an update available for the BIOS? Honestly I would try a PS/2 to USB adapter, they're 2-4 bucks.

Comment: Try the usb port next to the ethernet port. Try another keyboard, one without any hot buttons or added features.